# Text to csv converter

Tags: python

I have a use case to convert text file or command output to csv file.

My output of current text file is as below:

File 1.test

```
Use  Yes
Mode Enabled
```

File 2.test

```
Use  No
Mode Disabled
```

File 3.test

```
Use  Partial
Mode enabled
```

I want to generate output in csv file as below:

```
File    Use    Mode
1.test  Yes     Enabled
2.test  No      Disabled
3.test  Partial Enabled
```

I'm stuck with proper method for this...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.
Here's some hints to get un-stuck It's easy to open and read text files in Python. It also comes with a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module that makes generating files in that format relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using csv module:

```
import csv

data = []
files = ['File 1.test', 'File 2.test', 'File 3.test']
csv_columns = ["file_name", "Use", "Mode"]
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    for file in files:
        file_data = {"file_name" : file}
        with open("/Users/hbohra/Downloads/test-data/{0}".format(file)) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                file_data.update({line.split()[0]: line.split()[1]})
            writer.writerow(file_data)
```

Output file:

```
file_name,Use,Mode
File 1.test,Yes,Enabled
File 2.test,No,Disabled
File 3.test,Partial,enabled
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks hbohra.. this helps to get me going

Comment: Sure. What's required to do that. With bit changed in code it worked. Thanks

Comment: I believe you just need to click the tick (which only you can see) appearing on the left of my post.